# KDB How to update column values

Tags: kdb

I have a table which has column of symbol type like below.

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First | TP_RTD_FRV |
| Second | RF_QWE_FRV |
| Third | KF_FRV_POL |

I need to update it as below, wherever I have FRV, I need to replace it with AB_FRV. How to achieve this?

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First | TP_RTD_AB_FRV |
| Second | RF_QWE_AB_FRV |
| Third | KF_AB_FRV_POL |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q)t
name v
---------------
0    TP_RTD_FRV
1    RF_QWE_FRV
2    KF_FRV_POL
3    THIS
4    THAT
q)update `$ssr[;"FRV";"AB_FRV"]each string v from t
name v
------------------
0    TP_RTD_AB_FRV
1    RF_QWE_AB_FRV
2    KF_AB_FRV_POL
3    THIS
4    THAT
```

or without using qSQL

```
q)@[t;`v;]{`$ssr[;"FRV";"AB_FRV"]each string x}
name v
------------------
0    TP_RTD_AB_FRV
1    RF_QWE_AB_FRV
2    KF_AB_FRV_POL
3    THIS
4    THAT
```

Depending on the uniqueness of the data, you might benefit from [.Q.fu](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qfu-apply-unique)

```
q)t:1000000#t
q)\t @[t;`v;]{`$ssr[;"FRV";"AB_FRV"]each string x}
2343
q)\t @[t;`v;].Q.fu {`$ssr[;"FRV";"AB_FRV"]each string x}
10
```